# How to sum list of integers and save each step to new list?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm struggling to find simple-functional way to transform

```
val ints = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) into List(1, 3, 6, 10, 15)
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This operation is called [*prefix sum*, *cumulative sum*, or *inclusive scan*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum), the more generalized higher-order function is usually called `scan`. Scala provides [`scan`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#scan[B>:A,That](z:B)(op:(B,B)=>B)(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]):That) as part of its collections library:

```
ints.scan(0)(_ + _).tail
```

Comment: Short and simple as I hoped although scan call with default initial state as first element of list would be even better.

Comment: Like ints.scan(_ + _)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that there's an equivalent to [Haskell's `scanl1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl1) like there is with [`fold`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#fold[A1>:A](z:A1)(op:(A1,A1)=>A1):A1) / [`reduce`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#reduce[A1>:A](op:(A1,A1)=>A1):A1)

Comment: Looks like there isn't but same can be done by 
ints.tail.scan(ints.head)(_ + _)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foldLeft`, as follows:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5).foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) { case (acc, next) =>
     |   acc :+ next + acc.lastOption.getOrElse(0)
     | }
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 6, 10, 15)
```

In the partial function `(acc, next)`, `acc` is the currently accumulated list that starts as `List.empty[Int]`, and `next` is the next value in the provided list, starting with `1`.

Comment: OP said "*simple*-functional :)

Comment: Simplicity is relative :P

Answer (score 0):

```
ints.foldLeft(List[Int]())((acc,elem)=>elem+acc.headOption.getOrElse(0)::acc)
```

Comment: This results in a reversed list, so you'd need to call `.reverse` at the end.

Comment: Oops, I forgot, you're right. With :+ it would be better

Comment: @Chobeat no it wouldn't because the append would be O(N), as would the needed lastOption. Making the whole operation O(N*2)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, go on, another way to skin the cat:

```
ints.drop(1).foldLeft(List(ints.head))((acc,elem)=>elem+acc.head::acc).reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lee answer I modified it to

```
ints.tail.scan(ints.head)(_ + _)
```

Little longer but it treats first element as initial state.

Comment: use `ints.drop(1)...` then it won't throw an exception if `ints` is empty. –

Comment: This is also prone to exceptions if the collection is empty.